# How can `f();` be a declaration below?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, declaration, c++17

Excerpt from [DR 1990](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1990):

> In an example like
>
> ```
> void f() {
>     f();  // #1
> }
> ```
>
> The statement at #1 is ambiguous and can be parsed as either an expression or as a declaration.

Comment: Well, `int f();` is a valid declaration, and following the C++14 grammar, the *decl-specifier-seq* (`int` in the said declaraion) is optional, so `f();` is also a syntactically valid declaration....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is basically a technical issue with how the grammar was written. No sane vendor will actually report an ambiguity here.

In C++14 and earlier, we have a *simple-declaration* being, among other things,

> *decl-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> init-declarator-list*<sub>opt</sub> ;

Note that the *decl-specifier-seq* was optional.

Then we have a semantic requirement that the *decl-specifier-seq* can only be omitted in a constructor, destructor, or conversion function declaration, but that doesn't affect parsing.

A *simple-declaration* is a *block-declaration*, and a *block-declaration* is a *declaration-statement*, so the net effect is that in a *compound-statement* like

```
{
    f();
}
```

`f();` can be parsed either as a *declaration-statement* consisting of an (ill-formed) *simple-declaration* that has no *decl-specifier-seq*, or as an *expression-statement*.

The DR1990 change makes the *decl-specifier-seq* required in the *simple-declaration* production, and creates a separate *nodeclspec-function-declaration* production that is not a *block-declaration* for the no *decl-specifier-seq* case, so that the `f();` as-an-ill-formed-declaration parse is no longer possible inside a *compound-statement*.

Comment: This seems to be the correct answer. Thanks [@T.C.](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2756719/t-c) (+1).

Comment: To add to your initial disclaimer, I would say that it's probably a valid interpretation to say that "the decl-specifier-seq can only be omitted in a constructor, destructor, or conversion function declaration" is a syntactical requirement and therefore guides parsing, making it not really ambiguous. However this has never seemed to be really clear, so the clarification they did is certainly helpful.

Comment: See this statement in [ [dcl.dcl]/2 ](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.dcl#2): `A simple-declaration or nodeclspec-function-declaration of the form

attribute-specifier-seqopt decl-specifier-seqopt init-declarator-listopt ;`

This doesn't seem to be correct, as a *decl-specifier-seq* is not optional in a *simple-declaration*.

Comment: The Note in [ [dcl.dcl]/11 ](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.dcl#11) also seems to be incorrect: how would one declare a constructor, destructor, or a conversion function, that is **not** a template declaration.

Comment: @Ayrosa That note is correct as written. Different productions are used for the non-template cases.

Comment: @T.C. You wrote: "Then we have a semantic requirement that the decl-specifier-seq can only be omitted in a constructor, destructor, or conversion function declaration, but that doesn't affect parsing". But what do you mean by "doesn't affect parsing"? AFAICT, paragraph 11 in C++14 already inhibited `f();` from being interpreted as a declaration in `{ f(); }`. What am I missing?  `...` to be continued.

Comment: @T.C. Paragraph 11 in C++14: "Only in function declarations for constructors, destructors, and type conversions can the decl-specifier-seq be omitted."

Comment: @jab The declaration/expression-statement disambiguation is purely syntactic. As originally specified, the quoted paragraph only applies after the statement at issue has already been parsed as a declaration.

Comment: @T.C. `..., the quoted paragraph only applies after the statement at issue has already been parsed as a declaration.` Where in the standard does it say this?

Comment: @T.C. -1 from me

Comment: @Mao my guess is that constructors in normal classes are produced with [a different rule](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.mem#nt:member-declaration) (first one from that list).